# What is the meaning of Write-4 primitive?

Tags: exploit

What is the meaning of Write-4 primitive? In the exploit development tutorials, I meet a lot. Does it mean that write 32 bits into the register or memory?

Answer (score 2):

This is really dependent on the scenario and it'd help if you gave additional context to where you see this. I don't know what tutorial you are referring to but id I'd have to guess it'd be a *Write-What* primitive, the size of 32bit to memory.

A *Write-What* primitive is the ability to write whatever you want to a specific location **in memory** according to the exploited application.